# Combine lists, then remove from component list

Tags: java, collections

```
List<Bean> one //blah;
List<Bean> two //blah;
List<Bean> three //blah;

List<Bean> myCombined = Lists.newArrayList();
myCombined.addAll(one);
myCombined.addAll(two);
myCombined.addAll(three);
```

then if I remove from the underlying list, will it be removed from the combined list ?

```
one.remove(myBean)
one.contains(myBean); //false
myCombined.contains(myBean); //true or false ?
```

Best way to accomplish this if not ?

Comment: I really don't understand the downvotes to this question. Could someone please explain the reasons to downvote?

Comment: Really good question. Does anyone know if there is a library containing a version of `Iterables.concat` that returns a `List`?

Comment: Stack Overfloewer's "genius" really love to downvote as soon as the question don't teach them anything, which is against the real concept of knowledge sharing.

Comment: I downvoted because I expect more from a user with such a high reputation. The answer can be found by running the code provided. It can also be found by reading the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-). I see no effort.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeah, maybe it's not the best way to pose the real question, which I understand actually is `Best way to accomplish this if not ?`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't think reputation really matters. One could have 100k reputation from java tags and still ask noob question in haskell for example. I also don't think 22k is considered high reputation imho, but this is really subjective.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard The point is to have researched questions, not this. And I expect researched questions from someone who has been here 5 years with 1000 answers and 300 questions. The rest we can discuss on meta.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I agree on that, specially that after checking OP's profile, his most voted tag is java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addAll` copies the elements from the source list to the destination list.

Therefore, removing an element from `one` it will have no effect on `myCombined`.

### What to do?

To have a view of the list, you can use Guava [`Iterables.concat(...)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable...)):

```
Iterable<Bean> combinedView = Iterables.concat(one, two, three);
Iterables.contains(combinedView, myBean);  // true
one.remove(myBean);
Iterables.contains(combinedView, myBean);  // false
```

You can also use Java Stream:

```
Stream<Bean> combined = Stream.of(one, two, three)
                              .reduce(Stream.empty(), Stream::concat)
                              .map(identity());
```

Comment: Please note that the returned stream can only be used once.

Comment: I can't get the `Stream` bit to compile.

Answer (score 3):

`myCombined.contains(myBean);` will return true, as the List is a new object and does not refer to the other.

The best way to do this would be to create a method that clear each lists

```
public void removeObject(Bean b)
{
    this.one.remove(myBean);
    this.myCombined.remove(myBean);
}
```

Then simply call `removeObject(myBean)`.

Have a look at an example of the `addAll` method (from `ArrayList`)

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    Object[] a = c.toArray();
    int numNew = a.length;
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + numNew);  // Increments modCount
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);
    size += numNew;
    return numNew != 0;
}
```

You can clearly see that it create a copy.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, both lists will have references to the same object. So altering from `one` will alter on `myCombined`.

Removing from `one` will just delete the reference in `one`, but `myCombined` will keep track of its own reference.

Answer (score 2):

No, if you remove an element from one of the underlying lists, it won't "disappear" from the combined list, since the combined list is a new list, containing new references to the elements.

To accomplish what you want, you need a *list view* over the underlying lists. [Google Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) offers this by means of the [`Iterables.concat()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) method:

```
Iterable<Bean> combined = Iterables.concat(one, two, three);
```

Please note that the returned `Iterable` is not a `List`, but just an `Iterable`.